# Matlab code that needs some clarification

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm very beginner in Matlab and can't convert the following code to c++

suppose that conv is already written in C++, I don't know if the code is implementing a 2D conv or 1D actually

How would I convert the following code to C++

```
% Description:
%   Function that evaluates the equivalent loop transfer function from the
%   loop integrator gain
%
% Input:
%   KK      [real,vector]:  Integrator gains
%   N       [integer]    :  Order of the loop filter

% Output:
%   A      [real, vector]:  Coefficients of the denominator
%   B      [real, vector]:  Coefficients of the numerator
%
% Remarks:
%   o A rate-only NCO is assumed


% construct the loop filter transfer function
v1 = 1;
v2 = 1;

B = zeros(1, N);
for ii = N:-1:1,
    v1 = conv( v1, [1 -1] );
    B = B + KK(ii)*[v2 zeros(1, ii - 1)];
    v2 = conv(v2, [1 -1]);
end


v1 = conv( v1, [1 0]);

% Account for the rate-only NCO - Change this code to implement different
% NCO models
B = conv(B, [1 1])*1/2;
B = [ 0 B ];

A = v1 + B;
```

Comment: Use the Matlab coder application, to guide translation from Matlab to C or C++.

Comment: @Peter I did it looks so complicated and it doesn't really show a lot

Comment: That indeed needs clarification. For example, `v1 = conv( v1, [1 0]);` doesn’t do anything interesting except waste compute time. Why is that there?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I copied that from a book, I'm also confused, but if you can convert some part, then it would be very good step for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;
int main() {
    // v1 = 1;
    double v1 = 1;
    // v2 = 1;
    double v2 = 1;


    // B = zeros(1, N);
    vector<double> B(N, 0);
    //for ii = N:-1:1,
    for (int ii=N; ii>=1; ii--) {
        // v1 = conv( v1, [1 -1] );
        v1 = conv(v1, {1, -1});
        // B = B + KK(ii)*[v2 zeros(1, ii - 1)];
        vector<double> temp(v2.size() + ii - 1, 0); // initialize with zeros
        std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), temp.begin()); // copy v2 to temp
        B += temp * KK[ii];
        // v2 = conv(v2, [1 -1]);
        v2 = conv(v2, {1, -1});
    // end
    }


    // v1 = conv( v1, [1 0]);
    v1 = conv(v1, {1, 0});

    // B = conv(B, [1 1])*1/2;
    B = conv(B, {1, 1}) * 0.5;
    // B = [ 0 B ];
    B.insert(B.begin(), 0);

    // A = v1 + B;
    vector<double> A = v1 + B;
}
```